# How to toggle between Full screen and small Screen in custom media controller android

Tags: android, fullscreen, aspect-ratio, landscape-portrait, mediacontroller

i am using the following code for custom media controller. the code is working fine but if i try to toggle full screen in portrait mode  the video is stretched. if i give the fixed height and width the video is not stretched what is the proper way of implementing the toggle screen button in media controller.

**Video Controller:**

```
package your.package.name;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Locale;

import your.resource.path;

/**
 * A view containing controls for a MediaPlayer. Typically contains the
 * buttons like "Play/Pause", "Rewind", "Fast Forward" and a progress
 * slider. It takes care of synchronizing the controls with the state
 * of the MediaPlayer.
 * <p>
 * The way to use this class is to instantiate it programatically.
 * The MediaController will create a default set of controls
 * and put them in a window floating above your application. Specifically,
 * the controls will float above the view specified with setAnchorView().
 * The window will disappear if left idle for three seconds and reappear
 * when the user touches the anchor view.
 * <p>
 * Functions like show() and hide() have no effect when MediaController
 * is created in an xml layout.
 * 
 * MediaController will hide and
 * show the buttons according to these rules:
 * <ul>
 * <li> The "previous" and "next" buttons are hidden until setPrevNextListeners()
 *   has been called
 * <li> The "previous" and "next" buttons are visible but disabled if
 *   setPrevNextListeners() was called with null listeners
 * <li> The "rewind" and "fastforward" buttons are shown unless requested
 *   otherwise by using the MediaController(Context, boolean) constructor
 *   with the boolean set to false
 * </ul>
 */
public class VideoControllerView extends FrameLayout {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoControllerView";

    private MediaPlayerControl  mPlayer;
    private Context             mContext;
    private ViewGroup           mAnchor;
    private View                mRoot;
    private ProgressBar         mProgress;
    private TextView            mEndTime, mCurrentTime;
    private boolean             mShowing;
    private boolean             mDragging;
    private static final int    sDefaultTimeout = 3000;
    private static final int    FADE_OUT = 1;
    private static final int    SHOW_PROGRESS = 2;
    private boolean             mUseFastForward;
    private boolean             mFromXml;
    private boolean             mListenersSet;
    private View.OnClickListener mNextListener, mPrevListener;
    StringBuilder               mFormatBuilder;
    Formatter                   mFormatter;
    private ImageButton         mPauseButton;
    private ImageButton         mFfwdButton;
    private ImageButton         mRewButton;
    private ImageButton         mNextButton;
    private ImageButton         mPrevButton;
    private ImageButton         mFullscreenButton;
    private Handler             mHandler = new MessageHandler(this);

    public VideoControllerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mRoot = null;
        mContext = context;
        mUseFastForward = true;
        mFromXml = true;

        Log.i(TAG, TAG);
    }

    public VideoControllerView(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mUseFastForward = useFastForward;

        Log.i(TAG, TAG);
    }

    public VideoControllerView(Context context) {
        this(context, true);

        Log.i(TAG, TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        if (mRoot != null)
            initControllerView(mRoot);
    }

    public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerControl player) {
        mPlayer = player;
        updatePausePlay();
        updateFullScreen();
    }

    /**
     * Set the view that acts as the anchor for the control view.
     * This can for example be a VideoView, or your Activity's main view.
     * @param view The view to which to anchor the controller when it is visible.
     */
    public void setAnchorView(ViewGroup view) {
        mAnchor = view;

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        removeAllViews();
        View v = makeControllerView();
        addView(v, frameParams);
    }

    /**
     * Create the view that holds the widgets that control playback.
     * Derived classes can override this to create their own.
     * @return The controller view.
     * @hide This doesn't work as advertised
     */
    protected View makeControllerView() {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mRoot = inflate.inflate(R.layout.media_controller, null);

        initControllerView(mRoot);

        return mRoot;
    }

    private void initControllerView(View v) {
        mPauseButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.pause);
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(mPauseListener);
        }

        mFullscreenButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
        if (mFullscreenButton != null) {
            mFullscreenButton.requestFocus();
            mFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(mFullscreenListener);
        }

        mFfwdButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ffwd);
        if (mFfwdButton != null) {
            mFfwdButton.setOnClickListener(mFfwdListener);
            if (!mFromXml) {
                mFfwdButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        }

        mRewButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rew);
        if (mRewButton != null) {
            mRewButton.setOnClickListener(mRewListener);
            if (!mFromXml) {
                mRewButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        }

        // By default these are hidden. They will be enabled when setPrevNextListeners() is called 
        mNextButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
        if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
            mNextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mPrevButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.prev);
        if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
            mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller_progress);
        if (mProgress != null) {
            if (mProgress instanceof SeekBar) {
                SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) mProgress;
                seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekListener);
            }
            mProgress.setMax(1000);
        }

        mEndTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        mCurrentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_current);
        mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());

        installPrevNextListeners();
    }

    /**
     * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
     * automatically after 3 seconds of inactivity.
     */
    public void show() {
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }

    /**
     * Disable pause or seek buttons if the stream cannot be paused or seeked.
     * This requires the control interface to be a MediaPlayerControlExt
     */
    private void disableUnsupportedButtons() {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            if (mPauseButton != null && !mPlayer.canPause()) {
                mPauseButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (mRewButton != null && !mPlayer.canSeekBackward()) {
                mRewButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (mFfwdButton != null && !mPlayer.canSeekForward()) {
                mFfwdButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } catch (IncompatibleClassChangeError ex) {
            // We were given an old version of the interface, that doesn't have
            // the canPause/canSeekXYZ methods. This is OK, it just means we
            // assume the media can be paused and seeked, and so we don't disable
            // the buttons.
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
     * automatically after 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.
     * @param timeout The timeout in milliseconds. Use 0 to show
     * the controller until hide() is called.
     */
    public void show(int timeout) {
        if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
            setProgress();
            if (mPauseButton != null) {
                mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            }
            disableUnsupportedButtons();

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.BOTTOM
            );

            mAnchor.addView(this, tlp);
            mShowing = true;
        }
        updatePausePlay();
        updateFullScreen();

        // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
        // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
        // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);

        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FADE_OUT);
        if (timeout != 0) {
            mHandler.removeMessages(FADE_OUT);
            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, timeout);
        }
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        return mShowing;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the controller from the screen.
     */
    public void hide() {
        if (mAnchor == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            mAnchor.removeView(this);
            mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.w("MediaController", "already removed");
        }
        mShowing = false;
    }

    private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
        int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

        int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
        int hours   = totalSeconds / 3600;

        mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
        if (hours > 0) {
            return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
        } else {
            return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
        }
    }

    private int setProgress() {
        if (mPlayer == null || mDragging) {
            return 0;
        }

        int position = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        int duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
        if (mProgress != null) {
            if (duration > 0) {
                // use long to avoid overflow
                long pos = 1000L * position / duration;
                mProgress.setProgress( (int) pos);
            }
            int percent = mPlayer.getBufferPercentage();
            mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent * 10);
        }

        if (mEndTime != null)
            mEndTime.setText(stringForTime(duration));
        if (mCurrentTime != null)
            mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime(position));

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return true;
        }

        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        final boolean uniqueDown = event.getRepeatCount() == 0
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
        if (keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            if (uniqueDown) {
                doPauseResume();
                show(sDefaultTimeout);
                if (mPauseButton != null) {
                    mPauseButton.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY) {
            if (uniqueDown && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.start();
                updatePausePlay();
                show(sDefaultTimeout);
            }
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE) {
            if (uniqueDown && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.pause();
                updatePausePlay();
                show(sDefaultTimeout);
            }
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE) {
            // don't show the controls for volume adjustment
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            if (uniqueDown) {
                hide();
            }
            return true;
        }

        show(sDefaultTimeout);
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mPauseListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doPauseResume();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener mFullscreenListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doToggleFullscreen();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
    };

    public void updatePausePlay() {
        if (mRoot == null || mPauseButton == null || mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        } else {
            mPauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }
    }

    public void updateFullScreen() {
        if (mRoot == null || mFullscreenButton == null || mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPlayer.isFullScreen()) {
            mFullscreenButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_shrink);
        }
        else {
            mFullscreenButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_fullscreen_stretch);
        }
    }

    private void doPauseResume() {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            mPlayer.start();
        }
        updatePausePlay();
    }

    private void doToggleFullscreen() {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        mPlayer.toggleFullScreen();
    }

    // There are two scenarios that can trigger the seekbar listener to trigger:
    //
    // The first is the user using the touchpad to adjust the posititon of the
    // seekbar's thumb. In this case onStartTrackingTouch is called followed by
    // a number of onProgressChanged notifications, concluded by onStopTrackingTouch.
    // We're setting the field "mDragging" to true for the duration of the dragging
    // session to avoid jumps in the position in case of ongoing playback.
    //
    // The second scenario involves the user operating the scroll ball, in this
    // case there WON'T BE onStartTrackingTouch/onStopTrackingTouch notifications,
    // we will simply apply the updated position without suspending regular updates.
    private OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
            show(3600000);

            mDragging = true;

            // By removing these pending progress messages we make sure
            // that a) we won't update the progress while the user adjusts
            // the seekbar and b) once the user is done dragging the thumb
            // we will post one of these messages to the queue again and
            // this ensures that there will be exactly one message queued up.
            mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromuser) {
            if (mPlayer == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (!fromuser) {
                // We're not interested in programmatically generated changes to
                // the progress bar's position.
                return;
            }

            long duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
            long newposition = (duration * progress) / 1000L;
            mPlayer.seekTo( (int) newposition);
            if (mCurrentTime != null)
                mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime( (int) newposition));
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
            mDragging = false;
            setProgress();
            updatePausePlay();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);

            // Ensure that progress is properly updated in the future,
            // the call to show() does not guarantee this because it is a
            // no-op if we are already showing.
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
        if (mFfwdButton != null) {
            mFfwdButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
        if (mRewButton != null) {
            mRewButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
        if (mNextButton != null) {
            mNextButton.setEnabled(enabled && mNextListener != null);
        }
        if (mPrevButton != null) {
            mPrevButton.setEnabled(enabled && mPrevListener != null);
        }
        if (mProgress != null) {
            mProgress.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
        disableUnsupportedButtons();
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        event.setClassName(VideoControllerView.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setClassName(VideoControllerView.class.getName());
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mRewListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mPlayer == null) {
                return;
            }

            int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            pos -= 5000; // milliseconds
            mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
            setProgress();

            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener mFfwdListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mPlayer == null) {
                return;
            }

            int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            pos += 15000; // milliseconds
            mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
            setProgress();

            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
    };

    private void installPrevNextListeners() {
        if (mNextButton != null) {
            mNextButton.setOnClickListener(mNextListener);
            mNextButton.setEnabled(mNextListener != null);
        }

        if (mPrevButton != null) {
            mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(mPrevListener);
            mPrevButton.setEnabled(mPrevListener != null);
        }
    }

    public void setPrevNextListeners(View.OnClickListener next, View.OnClickListener prev) {
        mNextListener = next;
        mPrevListener = prev;
        mListenersSet = true;

        if (mRoot != null) {
            installPrevNextListeners();

            if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml) {
                mNextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml) {
                mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface MediaPlayerControl {
        void    start();
        void    pause();
        int     getDuration();
        int     getCurrentPosition();
        void    seekTo(int pos);
        boolean isPlaying();
        int     getBufferPercentage();
        boolean canPause();
        boolean canSeekBackward();
        boolean canSeekForward();
        boolean isFullScreen();
        void    toggleFullScreen();
    }

    private static class MessageHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<VideoControllerView> mView; 

        MessageHandler(VideoControllerView view) {
            mView = new WeakReference<VideoControllerView>(view);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            VideoControllerView view = mView.get();
            if (view == null || view.mPlayer == null) {
                return;
            }

            int pos;
            switch (msg.what) {
                case FADE_OUT:
                    view.hide();
                    break;
                case SHOW_PROGRESS:
                    pos = view.setProgress();
                    if (!view.mDragging && view.mShowing && view.mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        msg = obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
                        sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000 - (pos % 1000));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity where i implemented the toggle screen logic for fullscreen:**

```
@Override
    public void toggleFullScreen() {

         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) videoSurface.getLayoutParams();
           params.width =  metrics.widthPixels;
            params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
            params.leftMargin = 0;
            videoSurface.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
```

for portrait mode the video is occupying the entire screen(video is stretched). how can i maintain the aspect ratio of the video with out stretching. by playing the video at center without loosing aspect ratio similar to youtube.

can any one please help me out in solving this issue. and let me know are there any open source projects for custom media controller with toggle screen options.

Comment: You need create method set full screen for toggleFullScreen, code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373674/how-to-implemenent-android-video-player-in-full-screen/22345894#22345894

Comment: Put a video view inside a layout and change the layout height and width according to your needs. keep videoview height and width as fill-parent.