# Android - Match parent on video view content

Tags: android, android-videoview

As you can check in the picture, the videoview have the max width but it contents does not.

This is my code, how can I resize the video inside in order to avoid that blank space.

main.layout

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ll_video_or_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentContsraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    ll_video_or_image.removeAllViews()
    val videoView = VideoView(this)
    val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
    ll_video_or_image.addView(videoView,params)
    prepareVideo(videoView,video_url)
}

private fun prepareVideo(videoView: VideoView, link: String){
    val mc = MediaController(this)
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView)
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView)
    val video = Uri.parse(link)
    videoView.setMediaController(mc)
    videoView.setVideoURI(video)
    videoView.start()
    //  videoView.seekTo(100)
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what's that `layout_height="220dp"` good for?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373674/how-to-implemenent-android-video-player-in-full-screen

Answer (score 0):

The ConstraintLayout is growing to parent size.

So change
`android:layout_height="220dp"` of your `LinearLayout` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`